# How to set start image on Galleria Theme Classic

Tags: javascript, jquery, drupal-7, galleria

I try to display a list of images through Drupal Views Slideshow, using Galleria plugin,
all works well,

how to set specific start image from my list?

I found this option

```
Galleria.configure({
    show: 4  //This option accept only integer as value,
});
```

I want pass image url to display it first
Any suggestion for api function to use?

Answer (score 0):

You can try the history plugin: http://galleria.io/docs/plugins/history/

It allows hashed URLs such as http://example.com/#4

Comment: tnx David,
I solve my problem by extending Drupal Views functional, so I get a number of image to display, and  send it to the Galleria,